# problem with count total record by sql in ignite tbale

Tags: sql, ignite

I had problem with count records in table/cache ignite (2.15). The total record with `select count(*)` SQL is not the same with result from getCacheSize API.
This issue does not happen with every table/cache in our DB.

Answer (score 0):

In general there's no guarantee in ***Ignite 2.X*** that those two values should match. One cache can contain several [query entities](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/SQL/sql-api#query-entities), you can see it as a few tables over a cache. It's even possible that there are entries that don't match any SQL-exposed [binary type](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/key-value-api/binary-objects#binary-type-and-binary-fields), for example it's possible ingest those values through the key-value [API](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/SQL/sql-key-value-storage#using-key-value-api).

In a nutshell - you can try using a [scan query](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/key-value-api/using-scan-queries#executing-scan-queries) to identify records that don't belong to your table.

Comment: @vladimin: So you mean that count total records by sql maybe is not correct in this case?

Comment: It should be correct in terms of SQL, I'm trying to say that not all the cache entries are *visible* through SQL APIs. You have inserted something that doesn't match with your table(s).